# Git: "propagate" rebase to other branches of the same root

Tags: git, git-rebase

I was wondering if this is possible to "propagate" rebase of the branch. Let's consider the following setup:

```
branchA *-*-*-*-*-*-<*>
               \
        branchB *-*-*-*
                       \
                branchC *-*-*-*
```

If there are some changes on branchA, that happened after branchB was created, a rebase of branchB might be needed. But if we rebase branchB, so that it then starts from commit <*>, branchC will not be automatically updated.

Do you possibly know if there is a way in Git to automatically rebase branches that have common ancestor when this ancestor branch is rebased (so in other words to "propagate" the rebase)?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: In git branches are just pointers to a commit. So I doubt there is an option in git to automatically rebase all child branches when a parent branch is rebased. Although it might be possible to do using scripts.

Comment: Thanks! If I understood you correctly, there is no tree-like structure with Git branches - is it correct?

Comment: Basically. The commits in git point to its parent(s) so it can create tree-like structures. But a branch in git is just a pointer to a commit. From a branch you can reach the earlier commits that the branch commit is pointing to. But branchB cannot find branchC.

Comment: Thank you very much for explanation. I'm still learning Git and previously I used system with a tree-like approach.

Comment: Careful! Your git history **is** a tree. But this tree is formed by the commits. The “branch” is just a pointer to a specific commit. So the branch is not a tree, but does point to a part of a tree.

Answer (score 1):

No, git does not contain functionality for that. But you can just do it yourself. Rebase `branchC` and then have a look at its history to find the commit that matches the one `branchB` points to. Note its SHA and run:

```
git branch -f branchB *newSHA*
```

A situation like this should be very rare, as you should not rewrite published history and your local unpublished history is usually straight and unbranched.

Comment: Thank you very much. I managed to achieve that also using rebase --onto command. Thanks!

Comment: Actually I have a related question - when I merge one branch to another will I need to rebase the merged branch every time I rebase the "main" branch? In other words--in order to prevent unnecessary reabases should I always delete the branch that has been merged to other branch?

Comment: Do not mix rebasing and merging! Rebasing merges will cause a horrible mess. So to answer your question: don’t even get there :).